# Не удаётся вывести изображение с камеры с помощью OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Недавно стал пробовать ковырять OpenCV и столкнулся со следующей проблемой: вместо вывода изображения с камеры появляется окошко с перечёркнутой камерой[image: Окно со значком перечёркнутой камеры]

Вот код

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("camera", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Камера внешняя и только одна. В других приложениях работает исправно.
Если меняю ID камеры на 0, то вообще никаких окон не появляется, но и ошибку не выдаёт. При ID 2 и более выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: меняйте ID камеры на 0, запускайте и ждите. У меня, к примеру, окно секунд через 7-10 появляется

Comment: @ZxNuClear Спасибо большое! Я 2 раза запускал скрипт, ставил таймер, и камера включалась в среднем через 2 минуты 8 секунд. Я не знаю с чем связана такая монструозная задержка, т.к. камера и железо нормальные, да и в других приложениях камера запускается мгновенно. В другом вопросе на Stackoverflow говорили что задержка может быть связана с использованием именно USB камеры вместо встроенной, т.к. она дольше откликается. В любом случае это намного лучше чем ничего, спасибо!